# HTML Table - Maintain column width proportion when table width 100%

Tags: html, css, css-tables

The default html `<table>` element seems to set column width how I want/expect straight out of the box.  The problem occurs when I try to set the entire table width to 100%, in which case each of the reasonably sized columns snap to an equal 1/n % of the total width.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about

[image: example of width sizing]

The second table looks terrible.  There is absolutely no need to start wrapping text in the first column, especially when there is now *more* available room.

The only difference is that the second table is set to `width:100%`.  Of course you can set exact pixel or percentage dimensions on each of the columns to scale relative to each other, but that starts hard coding some guess work as to how big each of the columns will be.  In this case, columns with only *View* or *Edit* links can be sized incredibly small and don't need to take up any extra with, while some could use a little more room to grow, like Name/Type that might have other longer/shorter values.

Q: Can I somehow maintain the proportional column formating while allowing the entire table to be sized at 100% of the available width?

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/dabpc4sL/)

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table th {
    background: lightblue;
}

table th, table td {
    border: lightgrey 1px solid;
    padding: .1em 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<h4>Width Not Set</h4>

<table id="example1" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Stop</th>
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2017</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>04/03/2018</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<h4>Width 100%</h4>

<table id="example2" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Stop</th>
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2017</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>04/03/2018</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: mystery downvote? hey, at least there's an [mcve] here and some existing debugging steps.  don't see the harm in not knowing something.

Comment: Agree, maybe this is not the most insightful CSS question ever, but the samples are impeccable and the problem is not too obvious, I don't think `table-layout` is in this list of most used CSS properties. I have seem a lot of questions with less quality without any downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the `table-layout: fixed` rule that you added to the `table` tag, just remove it. From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp):

> `fixed`: Fixed table layout algorithm:
>
> - **The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells**
> - Allows a browser to lay out the table faster than the automatic table layout
> - The browser can begin to display the table once the first row has been received

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    /*table-layout: fixed;*/
}

table th {
    background: lightblue;
}

table th, table td {
    border: lightgrey 1px solid;
    padding: .1em 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<h4>Width Not Set</h4>

<table id="example1" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Stop</th>
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2017</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>04/03/2018</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<h4>Width 100%</h4>

<table id="example2" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Stop</th>
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2017</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>04/03/2018</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: uhm, yep, that'll do it.  I tried toggling that on and off in dev tools to see if it made any impact, but I'm guessing at that point it had already rendered and made up it's mind.  I should have done a clean run from the start with and without it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

**Note:** ***I removed the `width:100%` from both the tables, the CSS works best without this set!***

The Code is from old SO post. Refer below.

<kbd>**SO Answer**</kbd>

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table th {
  background: lightblue;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: lightgrey 1px solid;
  padding: .1em 0.2em;
}
tr td:last-child{
    width:1%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h4>Width Not Set</h4>

<table id="example1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Stop</th>
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2017</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>04/03/2018</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<h4>Width 100%</h4>

<table id="example2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Stop</th>
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2017</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>04/03/2018</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

















<div style='position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0; background:lightgray;width:100%;'>
  About this SO question:
  <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/q/46247387/1366033'>
        HTML Table - Maintain column width proportion when table width 100%
    </a>
</div>
https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/dabpc4sL/
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's an attempt at a solution

Leverage the initial rendering of the table as is to establish the relative column sizes.  Loop through each and set the size explicitly so they'll remain in the same proportion once the table is programmatically resized to 100%

```js
function LockColumnWidthAndResize($table) {
    $table.find('tr th').each(function() {
      $(this).width($(this).width())
    });
    $table.width("100%");
}
```

[image: Example]

**Pros**: Doesn't require hard coding in widths of content ahead of time
**Cons**: Little Kludgy and has a bit of a Flash of Unstyled Content.

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/dabpc4sL/2/)

#### Demo in StackSnippets

```js
$(function() {

  LockColumnWidthAndResize($('#example2'))

  function LockColumnWidthAndResize($table) {
    $table.find('tr th').each(function() {
      $(this).width($(this).width())
    });
    $table.width("100%");
  }
  
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table th {
    background: lightblue;
}

table th, table td {
    border: lightgrey 1px solid;
    padding: .1em 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Width Not Set</h4>

<table id="example1" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Stop</th>
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2017</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>04/03/2018</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<h4>Width - Set 100% dynamically</h4>

<table id="example2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Stop</th>
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2017</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>04/03/2018</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Regular Size Name</td>
      <td>Adjustment</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pretty Long Name Size Actually</td>
      <td>Order</td>
      <td>08/01/2017</td>
      <td>02/02/2019</td>
      <td><a href="#View">View</a></td>
      <td><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```